# Ionic app not recognizing speech in android mobile

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, speech-recognition

I wanted to design an ionic app that listens to voice commands by following the tutorial [here](http://devgirl.org/2016/01/08/speaking-with-cordova/)
But the app seems to recognize the voice commands over the microphone if tested on my computer using the `var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition(); //To Computer` command.But on seeing this [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/speech-recognition-solved/42205/4) I replaced the command to

`var recognition = new SpeechRecognition(); // To Device`

But this dosen't seem to work on my android device..
Has anybody faced the same issue with [SpeechRecognitionPlugin](https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin) ?
Please share your thoughts and reviews...Thanks

Comment: Did someone got it to work on Android Marshmallow? I m stuck too with the same issue but not using Ionic though

Comment: Have posted the code which i tested on Android 6 device. Give it a shot after adding cordova media plugin.

Comment: Adding media plugin doesn't work for me! Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to crack it. The trick was to add the [cordova media plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media).

The working code is as follows:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>        
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Speech Recognition</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form>
        Click to speak <input type="button" value="speak" name="Download" id="speak" />  <br>
        <input type="text" id="q" name="q" size=60>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

var recognition;
function onDeviceReady() {  

    $('#speak').click( function() {
        recognition = new SpeechRecognition();          
        recognition.onresult = function(event) {
            if (event.results.length > 0) {
                console.log(event.results[0][0].transcript);                
                q.value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            }
        };      
        recognition.start();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The timeout workaround isn't working for me. However, I did notice that I get almost 100% results if I speak IMMEDIATELY after the beep. I added a prompt to the user if no words are found.

Here is an example based on my approach:

```
var recording = false;
var spokenInput = '';

function startRecognition() {
    if (!recording) {

        recording = true;
        spokenInput = '';

        var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

        recognition.onresult = function(event) {
            if (event.results.length > 0) {
                spokenInput = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            }
        };

        recognition.onend = function() {
            recording = false;
            if (spokenInput) {
               alert(spokenInput);
            } else {
                alert('For best results, try speaking immediately after the beep!');
            }
        };

        setTimeout(function() {
            recognition.stop();
        }, 6000); // Force stop  after 6 seconds

        recognition.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Still I'm not able to record my voice over the phone.I think its the problem with var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

Comment: @forgottofly I forgot to add the start method. Fixed.